# Checking when more than one dataframe column has specific values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have data that is in the form that looks like:

```
Shop              Date             Produced         Lost        Output     Signal
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          0              1            9          1
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          11             1            11         0
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          0              0            0          2
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          1              0            0          2
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          5              7            0          2
.
.
.
.
```

The data SHOULD have values for **'Lost'** and **'Output'** that are 0 when **'Produced'** is 0 but that's not the case. I need a way to find out when this isn't the case (when Produced is 0 but any of Lost, Output, or Signal are not 0).

Making a counter that counts the times this is true or not is what I used to see the number like:

```
counter = 0

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['Produced'] and row['Lost'] != 0:
        counter += 1
    else:
        continue
```

I'd like to see exactly which rows in the dataframe these are (it's a large set) and this is hardly very efficient to search by each row.

Is there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
data[(data['Produced'] == 0) & (data['Lost'] != 0) & (data['Output'] != 0) & (data['Signal'] != 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a very simple and clean way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Boolean indexing and [`pd.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html). For readability, you can store masks in variables:

```
m1 = data['Produced'] == 0
m2 = (data[['Lost', 'Output', 'Signal']] != 0).all(1)

res = data[m1 & m2]
```

Comment: I think they want `any`: "...when Produced is 0 but any of Lost, Output, or Signal are not 0)."

Comment: @SpghttCd, Possibly. But the accepted answer has `&` everywhere which implies `all`. So not entirely sure there.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be boolean indexing with one array for the `==0` part (`Produced`) and one for the `!=0` part, packed via `loc` and `any`:

```
df[df.Produced==0 & (df.loc[:, ['Lost', 'Output', 'Signal']]!=0).any(1)]
```